# Suppose $X_{n}$ is series of random variables such that it is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} E(X_{n}^{4}) < \infty$. Prove that $X_{n} \rightarrow 0$ a.s.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, random-variables, means

Suppose $X_{n}$ is series of random variables such that it is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} E(X_{n}^{4}) < \infty$. According to Markov's inequality we know that $$P(\lvert X_{n} \rvert > \epsilon) \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon^{4}} \cdot E(\lvert X_{n} \rvert ^{4}).$$ Using the assumption we have: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(\lvert X_{n} \rvert > \epsilon)\ \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon^{4}} \cdot \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} E(\lvert X_{n} \rvert ^{4}).$$ Therefore, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(\lvert X_{n} \rvert > \epsilon)\ < \infty$ which implies $X_{n} \rightarrow 0$ a.s. I hope that proof is correct :)

Comment: Are you implicitly using the (extended) Borel-Cantelli lemma in your final statement?

Comment: It is correct though some more details could have been given.

Comment: @EkeneE. yes, exactly that

Comment: Okay then I think it's correct (if maybe a bit incomplete).